# How to return a Key from HashMap based on its Value in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, key-value

Consider the following:

```
for (Boolean i: x.values()) {
    if (i == false) {
        return // KEY;
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am trying to iterate through the `HashMap`. And I want to return a *Key* when the value is `false`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the HashMap's `entrySet`:

```java
for (Map.Entry<Object, Boolean> entry : x.entrySet()) {
   if(entry.getValue() == false){
        return entry.getKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to find first a key that is mapped to a particular value you need to iterate either over the *key set* or over the *entry set*.

The latter option is preferred because at each iteration step you will have a *key-value pair* on your hands. Therefore, it would be slightly faster than interrogating the map at every iteration (***remainder:** there could be collisions in a real hashmap, and finding the target node can take more time than accessing the value on a map-entry*).

But you definitely can't use a collection of *map values* returned by a method `values()` like you're doing in the code-snippet you've posted. There's no fast way of retrieving a *key* when you have only a *value* on your hands.

In the example below, ill show how to obtain a *key* from a map of arbitrary type that matches the condition (a `Predicate`) provided dynamically at runtime using **Stream API**.

There's one important thing to consider: target value might not be present in the map. And the code should handle this case. We can provide a default value (either directly or via `Supplier`), throw an exception (if according to the application logic the given value is always expected to be present), or by utilizing methods `ifPresent()`, `ifPresentOrElse()` provided by the `Optional` class. In the example below, I've chosen to provide a default value.

*Take a look at these tutorials for more information on* [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) *and* [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Boolean> sourceMap =
        Map.of("A", true, "B", false, "C", true);
    
    String result = getFirstKey(sourceMap, entry -> !entry.getValue(), "");
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static <K, V> K getFirstKey(Map<K, V> map,
                                   Predicate<Map.Entry<K, V>> condition,
                                   K defaultKey) {
    
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(condition)         // Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>>
        .findFirst()               // Optional<Map.Entry<K, V>>
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)    // Optional<K>
        .orElse(defaultKey); // or apply .orElseThrow() depending on your needs
}
```

*Output*

```
B // key assosiated with a value of `false`
```